# Error when QuerySnapshot runs in Firestore - Throws error Skipping epollex becuase skipping EPOLLEX GRPC_LINUX_EPOLL is not defined

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a function to pull a random document from my firestore collection, which then returns a FIRQuery. Once i got that, I created a model file to parse any FIRQuery data from my firestore document. However, once i run it and attempt to print it to the log, I get the response of "Skipping epollsig becuase GRPC_LINUX_EPOLL is not defined." 4 times, which makes sense as i am trying to print 4 fields of my document. My code for the parsing is below - keep in mind any CAPS values are constants that are just defined as equal to exactly how they read in the firestore document field

```
class randomModel {

private(set) var quote: String!
private(set) var randomInt: Int!
private(set) var approved: Bool!
private(set) var source: String!

init(approved: Bool, quote: String, randomInt: Int, source: String)
{
    self.approved = approved
    self.quote = quote
    self.randomInt = randomInt
    self.source = source


}

class func parseData(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?) -> [randomModel] {
    var quoteStructure = [randomModel]()

    guard let snap = snapshot else {return quoteStructure}

    for document in (snap.documents) {
        let data = document.data()
        let quote = data[DATABASE_QUOTE_VALUE_FIELD] as? String
        let randomInt = data[DATABASE_RANDOM_INTEGER_VALUE_FIELD] as? Int
        let approved = data[DATABASE_APPROVED_VALUE_FIELD] as? Bool
        let source = data[DATABASE_SOURCE_VALUE_FIELD] as? String

        let parsedData = randomModel(approved: approved!, quote: quote!, randomInt: randomInt!, source: source!)

        quoteStructure.append(parsedData)
    }
    return quoteStructure
}
```

Then my code to actually print the data and pull a random document is here:

```
 @IBAction func generatePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let quoteRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Quotes")
    let queryRef = quoteRef.whereField(DATABASE_RANDOM_INTEGER_VALUE_FIELD, isGreaterThan: 1)
    .order(by: "randomInt")
    .limit(to: 1)
        .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("Error Fetching Document \(err)")
            } else {
                print(randomModel.parseData(snapshot: snapshot))

            }
    } 
}
```

So can someone guide me as to what I am doing wrong to throw this error. My Document structure looks like this in firestore.. sorry, I don't have any rep to be able to embed into a post yet. Thanks for the help in advance!!

[image: Document Structure Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13855) that was fixed in gRPC 1.8.4. Run `pod update`.

Comment: This fixed the bug, but now is returning [The_Donald.randomModel] The_Donald being my database in firestore

Comment: Glad the GRPC_LINUX_EPOLL issue is fixed. Sounds like you have a different question now.